# carriage return on mssql output in bat file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, command, carriage-return

so I am trying to get both mssql fields to output on separate lines but can not seem to figure out the proper command to implement this effect

I am currently using a `,` seperator but need the fields to be on separate lines in the TXT output file

so instead of abc,def I need

```
abc
def
```

this is what I am currently using

```
 sqlcmd -S .\database -U sa -P password1 -d family -Q "select name, age from setup" -s"," -w -h -1 -o "C:\familysave.txt"
```

Comment: You can try `select CONCAT(name, CHAR(13), CHAR(10), age) from setup`. The `CONCAT()` function concatenates strings together, which will eliminate the commas between fields. `CHAR(13)` and `CHAR(10)` produce carriage-return and line-feed characters.

Comment: I did that removed the -w left in the -h -1 and still get the (1 rows affected) at the end of the file can I remove that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to calculate that result.

This is my approach:

```
-- Step 1: create rownumber into #temp

select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name ASC) AS Row,
    name, age 
into 
    #temp 
from 
    setup

--- Step 2: Join tables and using rownumber * 10 and 11 to get new order

SELECT name
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         Row * 10 as Row,
         name 
     FROM #temp
     UNION
     SELECT
         row * 11, CAST(age AS varchar(100))
     FROM #temp) T 
ORDER BY
    row
```

Results

```
name
Carlos
25
Cecilia
21
Juan
20
Maria
22
```

Sample data

```
insert into setup values ('Juan', 20)
insert into setup values ('Carlos', 25)
insert into setup values ('Maria', 22)
insert into setup values ('Cecilia', 21)
```

Happy coding.

PS: create SQL into stored procedure to run from sqlcmd using EXEC SP_NAME

Tested on:

```
 select @@VERSION

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4583460) - 13.0.5108.50 (X64)   May 20 2022 20:28:29   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
```